# Unable to get cron daemon to start on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have an `Ubuntu 10.04 server`.  I'm trying to start the cron daemon but it will not start.
I'm using the command (as `root`):

```
service cron start
```

When I execute this command - it just hangs.  I'm not seeing any information in the `syslog` as to what might be going on.

`service cron stop` does the same thing - it just hangs.

Any ideas what I can check to see what is preventing `cron` from starting?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all the system needed was a reboot.  It was sitting idle with an app not cycling for 2.5 months - so it had fouled a bunch of processes and memory.  Once I rebooted - cron started just fine.

Thanks!